# How does admin identify routers connected to a network?

Tags: router, monitoring

In my campus, we are provided with a LAN port to each room to access the internet. Also, they didn't allow students to use routers in their respective room. The only way one can access the internet is via LAN port or use your personal cellular network.

Recently I came across *TP-Link Archer C20* router and saw it supported MAC-Cloning. I cloned my laptop mac address to it and changed the router hostname to my laptop model name. For a month, everything was working fine. All my smart devices can use the internet and were working fine.
Today, I observed that my room's LAN Port was down.

**Things my university IT department do to ensure no routers are connected to it:**

- For what I gathered talking with the workers and people was that they perform an automatic scan when a device is connected to a network. They cross-check the mac address and if found of a router or switch they close down to that port.
  Also, this scan is done weekly from what I can guess.

**Things I did to ensure my router is hidden on a network:**

- Used netdiscover to scan my hostel's local network from my friend pc and saw the mac and hostname of my router was of that of my Laptop.

How did the university admin figure out I was using a router? Since MAC address and hostname were the same as my laptop. Is there any other way?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: We can't tell you why someone else did something.

Comment: "All my smart devices can use the internet and were working fine. " my guess was that all that traffic didn't look like a laptop's network traffic.

Comment: `They cross-check the mac address` - Note that, unless you specifically were required to register your laptop MAC address (or are using a laptop they provide, although this also is problematic), you wouldn't have needed to clone your laptop's address specifically; MAC addresses include organization/identifier ids, so you'd just need something from any non-router device (ie, like an old desktop at home).  Besides any traffic differences, if they're going to this effort they may be sweeping for unauthorized wireless signals.